# Booting Existing Linux Installation in qemu VM

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, kvm, uefi

There are 2 separate arch installations on my machine, one on an **nvme** drive and another on **/dev/sda** (**EFI** in **/dev/sda1** and **root** in **/dev/sda2**). Trying to boot the arch on **/dev/sda** from inside the arch of **nvme** with the following command

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 4096 \
    -cpu host \
    -smp 6 \
    -drive file=/dev/sda1,format=raw \
    -drive file=/dev/sda2,format=raw \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd \
    -vga virtio \
    -display sdl \
    -net nic \
    -boot order=c\
    -d guest_errors
```

- OVMF_CODE.fd and OVMF_VARS.fd  are at the correct location and are valid
- **GRUB** is installed on both guest and host
- **/dev/sda** partitions are unmounted
- also tried running without `sudo` and making the ovmf files accessible to the logged in user
- also tried `-bios` option with `OVMF.fd` file

But the command just shows a blank screen and the process apparently hangs.
Could you tell me how to fix this.

Comment: My guess would be you map a partition as a drive, where the guest system won't find partitions inside.

Comment: Do you mean giving just 'file=/dev/sda' instead of separate partitions sda1 and sda2? Tried that, but it gives the same result, just there are a bunch of messages: 'Invalid read at addr 0xFED40000, size 1, region '(null)', reason: rejected' on console with varying addr.

Comment: I meant that yes. But from what you tell it appears that's not enough. No more idea.